# python networking: asynchat handshake

Tags: python, networking, asynchronous, asyncore

I am using python asynchat to implement a network protocol.
At connection time I need to send a command and the server answer with a session.

My main problem is that I need to wait until I get the session response. but not sure how to implement this. should I use socket.recv for the connection setup? is a good idea?

Comment: You can use the [select](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html) package? Or if you are using blocking sockets, just do a `recv` and it will block until there is something to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When writing a network application using asynchronous techniques, you *wait* by recording your state somewhere and then letting the main loop continue.  At some future time, the data you're waiting for will become available, the main loop will notify you of that fact, and you can combine the new data with the recorded state to complete whatever task you are working on.  Depending on the specific task, you may need to go through this cycle many times before your task is actually done.

These ideas are basically the same regardless of what asynchronous system you're using.  However, [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/) is [a vastly superior system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384360/which-python-async-library-would-be-best-suited-for-my-code-asyncore-twisted) to [asynchat](http://docs.python.org/library/asynchat.html), so I'm not going to try to explain any of the asynchat details.  Instead, here's an example that does the kind of thing you're asking about, using Twisted:

```
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint
from twisted.internet import reactor

# Stream-oriented connections like TCP are handled by an instance 
# of a Protocol subclass
class SomeKindOfClient(Protocol):

     # When a new connection is established, the first thing that
     # happens is this method is called.
     def connectionMade(self):
         # self.transport is set by the superclass, and lets us 
         # send data over the connection
         self.transport.write("GREETING")

         # a Deferred is a generic, composable API for specifying
         # callbacks
         self.greetingComplete = Deferred()

         # Here's some local state
         self._buffer = ""

     # Whenever bytes arrive on the TCP connection, they're passed
     # to this method
     def dataReceived(self, bytes):

         # Incorportate the network event data into our local state.
         #  This kind of buffering is always necessary with TCP, because
         # there's no guarantees about how many bytes will be delivered
         # at once (except that it will be at least 1), regardless of
         # the size of the send() the peer did.
         self._buffer += bytes

         # Figure out if we're done - let's say the server response is 32
         # bytes of something
         if len(self._buffer) >= 32:
             # Deliver it to whomever is waiting, by way of the Deferred
             # object
             greeting, self._buffer = self._buffer[:32], self._buffer[32:]
             complete = self.greetingComplete
             self.greetingComplete = None
             complete.callback(greeting)

         # Otherwise we'll keep waiting until dataReceived is called again
         # and we have enough bytes.


# One of the normal ways to create a new client connection
f = Factory()
f.protocol = SomeKindOfClient
e = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, "somehost", 1234)

# Connect returns one of those Deferreds - letting us specify a function
# to call when the connection is established.  The implementation of
# connect is also doing basically the same kind of thing as you're asking
# about.
d = e.connect(f)

# Execution continues to this point before the connection has been
# established.  Define a function to use as a callback when the connection
# does get established.
def connected(proto):
    # proto is an instance of SomeKindOfClient.  It has the 
    # greetingComplete attribute, which we'll attach a callback to so we
    # can "wait" for the greeting to be complete.
    d = proto.greetingComplete

    def gotGreeting(greeting):
        # Note that this is really the core of the answer.  This function
        # is called *only* once the protocol has decided it has received
        # some necessary data from the server.  If you were waiting for a
        # session identifier of some sort, this is where you might get it
        # and be able to proceed with the remainder of your application
        # logic.
        print "Greeting arrived", repr(greeting)

    # addCallback is how you hook a callback up to a Deferred - now
    # gotGreeting will be called when d "fires" - ie, when its callback
    # method is invoked by the dataReceived implementation above.
    d.addCallback(gotGreeting)

# And do the same kind of thing to the Deferred we got from 
# TCP4ClientEndpoint.connect
d.addCallback(connected)

# Start the main loop so network events can be processed
reactor.run()
```

To see how this behaves, you can launch a simple server (eg `nc -l 1234`) and point the client at it.  You'll see the greeting arrive and you can send some bytes back.  Once you've sent back 30, the client will print them (and then hang around indefinitely, because I implemented no further logic in that protocol).

Comment: great with your example I know how to write the asynchat solution. anyways I thought to use twisted but, I am rewriting a python activemq opensource driver. I want minimal requiriments. Thanks!

Comment: Having minimal requirements means you're trading higher development costs for some kind of installation convenience - fewer things to install, or smaller installed footprint, etc.  Installation is easy, though - it's frequently automated so as to be effectively free, plus Twisted is already installed on millions of computers (eg, about 1/3rd of all Debian installs already have it).  Installed footprint might be a concern, but only on extremely small devices, and even those have lots of room these days (how much does 8GB of flash cost?).  Besides, Python itself is larger than Twisted.

Comment: Just to let you know, I also love twisted :)