# How to catch Python3 SocketIO error

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, exception, socket.io

I'm making a simple app that uses [socketIO_client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/socketIO-client). I can't figure out how to "catch" the error when the connection fails.

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace
sock = SocketIO("localhost", 3000, LoggingNamespace)
```

When the server is offline the following is printed in the console:

```
WARNING:root:localhost:3000/socket.io [waiting for connection] HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=3000): Max retries exceeded with url: /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1455989769325-0 (Caused by <class 'ConnectionRefusedError'>: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

But an exception isn't raised that I can catch and I tried creating my own namespace class with `on_error`, `on_disconnect`, and `on_event`functions defined but none of them were executed. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714822/python3-catch-errors-when-from-self-connectbadhost-6667) didn't work either.

How can I "catch" this error so I can handle it properly? Alternatively, where can I find more detailed documentation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LoggingMixin` of `socketIO_client` very explicitly turns the exception into a string and logs it; you'll have to subclass `SocketIO` and customise the loop that implements retrying things for a number of seconds. If you simply want to let the exception bubble up the first time it occurs (independent of the time-out):

from socketIO_client import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace
import socketIO_client.logs

```
class MySocketIO(SocketIO):

    def _yield_warning_screen(self, seconds=None):
        yield from socketIO_client.logs._yield_elapsed_time(seconds)

sock = MySocketIO("localhost", 3000, LoggingNamespace)
```

For more complex behaviour like raising only after timing out, a more complex loop implementation in place of the transparent `yield from` is needed.